# Generic XHR caching function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've made a simple caching function for my jQuery ajax calls.

I know about the `$.ajax()` `cache` setting, but I don't use it for various reasons. One of the most important one is it being limited to GET (and perhaps HEAD?) requests.

If a cached value is found, and is a reference type, I'm returning a deep copy rather than a reference to the actual object.

```
var cache = {};
function getData(cacheKey, getPromise) {

    var dfd = $.Deferred(),
        cachedValue = cache[cacheKey];

    if (!cachedValue) {

        getPromise().done(function (response) {

            console.log('got data from XHR', response);

            cache[cacheKey] = response;
            dfd.resolve(response);

        }).fail(dfd.reject);

    } else {

        console.log('got data from cache', cachedValue);

        if ($.type(cachedValue) === 'object')
            dfd.resolve($.extend(true, {}, cachedValue));
        else if ($.type(cachedValue) === 'array')
            dfd.resolve($.extend(true, [], cachedValue));
        else
            dfd.resolve(cachedValue);
    }

    return dfd.promise();
}
```

Sample use case:

```
var getter = $.ajax.bind(this, {
    url:'/echo/json/',
    data: data,
    type: 'POST'
});

getData('foo', getter).done(function(){
    getData('foo', getter);
    getData('foo', getter);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rg5ntyt5/

Please share your thoughts regarding possible improvements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery already has a caching mechanism - and I'm not just talking `cache: true` (which as you say, only works for HEAD/GET, and relies on the browser's built-in caching).

What I'm talking about is promises. Promises are caches themselves, and `$.ajax` returns a promise. Once resolved or rejected, it'll stay that way, and you can keep calling `done/fail/then/always` on it, being passed the same arguments every time. The request isn't repeated.

So to start, your example code can be written as just:

```
var xhr = $.ajax.bind(this, {
    url:'/echo/json/',
    data: data,
    type: 'POST'
})();

xhr.done(function (response) { ... });
xhr.done(function (response) { ... });
xhr.done(function (response) { ... });
// etc...
```

As long as you have a reference to `xhr`, the request and response is cached.

The only difference from yours is that the response is passed as-is without the deep copy. But if your requests are JSON, you can always get a pristine response by re-parsing the response yourself:

```
xhr.done(function (response, status, xhr) {
  var pristineResponse = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
});
```

Incidentally, your example didn't make much sense. You called `getData` a couple of times but didn't actually do anything with those calls. Besides, calling it from inside the `done` callback, seems redundant to me:

```
getData('foo', getter).done(function (response) { // <- the response is right there, no caching necessary
    // do stuff with response. For instance, a deep copy.
});
```

Not to be harsh, but your current implementation is just kinda pointless, it seems to me. You have to create the getter function, and then manually pass it to `getData`. Then, if you want to use the cache... you have to pass the getter function again? Shouldn't that just be `getData('foo')` without the getter if you want the cache? As mentioned, if you have the request's promise, you have a cache already.

However, even if you just call `getData('foo')`, you have to be prepared to handle a failure, if nothing's been cached. Which, in turn, means that you have to always be ready to perform the request, so you code will be littered with something like this:

```
getData('foo')
  .done(function (response) {
    // with no existing cache, this won't be called
  })
  .fail(function () {
    // instead we'll have to create the cache
    var getter = $.ajax.bind(something, { // oops, what "this" should we bind to?
      url:'/echo/json/',
      data: data,
      type: 'POST'
    });
    getData('foo', getter).done(function (response) {
      // finally! We can get our response
    });
  });
```

And you'd have to do this *every time*, because you don't know if you have a cache or not.

Finally, there's a risk of a race condition. You only set the cache when the request is completed successfully, so if you were to do this:

```
var getter = $.ajax.bind(this, {
    url:'/echo/json/',
    data: data,
    type: 'POST'
});

// This performs a request. It's asynchronous, so the code here just continues on immediately...
getData('foo', getter);

// ... so this performs *another* request, because nothing's been cached yet
getData('foo', getter);

// Time passes, and the first request completes. A cache is finally created.
// Then the second request completes, and overwrites the just-created cache.
```

I imagine that's why your example only tried using the cache inside the first `done` handler. But that's the one place where you *don't* need the cache, since you have the response.

So, really, I see little benefit in using your code. The only thing it seems to add is the deep copy.

If you want a simpler caching mechanism, I'd suggest something like this:

```
  var cache = {};
  function cachedAJAX(options) {
    if(!options.cacheKey) {
      return $.ajax(options); // no caching requested; just pass through
    }

    if(!cache[options.cacheKey]) {
      cache[options.cacheKey] = $.ajax(options); // create and cache a new request
    }

    // return the request
    return cache[options.cacheKey];
  };
```

Now, instead of calling `$.ajax`, you'd call `cachedAJAX`, but you'd use all the same options (`url`, `type`, `data`, etc.). There's just one extra option: `cacheKey`. If that's set, `cachedAJAX` won't perform a new request if it has a cached one. And it caches immediately, meaning you might cache a soon-to-be-failed request. But there's no race condition.

Comment: Thank you for a descriptive answer. I agree that my example is kind of silly - I just wanted to make it fetch data from the cache a couple of times. To elaborate, the caching function might not seem too useful in my example. But in my actual code, there are a lot of modules using this function in parallel, so I'll get a lot less server calls. That's also the reason why I'm always passing the getter function. I can't know if another module has made or finished a call yet.

Comment: @Johan Nor can you know if another module is making the request right now (the aforementioned race condition). In any event, the caching mechanism isn't "transparent" right now. You basically have to do a lot more work to use the caching. But if you can have the `getter` function available anywhere you need it (i.e. globally), you can also call it once, and make its _result_ available anywhere you need it instead.

Comment: I got your point. Regarding your last snippet, I've made a slight modofication based on your answer to return a pristine response from the cache: http://jsfiddle.net/q03ovtu7/ Any thoughts? Perhaps to be safe, you should check if it's a valid JSON string? I think the window.JSON API uses try...catch.

Comment: @Johan Yeah, `JSON.parse` may throw an exception. But jQuery will be the first the see it, and if there's an exception the promise won't be resolved to begin with. So you _should_ be safe to call `JSON.parse` in a `done` handler, but maybe not in a `fail` handler. Your code looks ok, but modifying the response before passing it down the chain also prevents you from (easily) passing on the 2nd and 3rd arguments along. So you'll have to hope you don't need them.

Comment: Hehe, I was just thinking about that actually. Just out of curiosity, how am I supposed to pass the rest of the arguments along?

Comment: @Johan Don't know actually... I was trying to figure that out myself, but I don't see a (simple) way. You'd probably have to create another promise and return that instead, resolving/rejecting it with copies of the usual arguments. But I'd be tempted to just forego the deep-copy-via-parsing instead, and just return the original promise unaltered. Ideally your code shouldn't be causing side-effects in the first place, so copying shouldn't be necessary. But if you _do_ need a copy somewhere, you can always parse the JSON _there_, because with the original promise you'll be passed `jqXHR`

Comment: I agree, it just crossed my mind that I didn't know how to solve it :) Thanks a lot for your time, I really appreciate it!

Comment: @Johan No prob - glad it was helpful